# hardhat-gas-reporter not to calculate(skip) gas tax in some transactions in the gas report

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, test

I use hardhat-gas-reporter package.
I want the gas tax not to be calculated for part of the transactions in one test in the gas report. Can this be done?
code example

```
it("Should deployed test", async function() {

   const { contract, owner, account1, account2 } = await loadFixture(
       deployContracts
   );

   let tx1;
   for(let i=1;i<5;i++) {
       tx1 = await contract.connect(account1).myCustomMethod(i, account1.address, 1);
       await tx1.wait();
   }

   let tx2;
   for(let i=6;i<10;i++) {
       /** @skip gas calculate this tx2 **/
       tx2 = await contract.connect(account1).myCustomMethod(i, account1.address, 1);
       await tx2.wait();
   }
});
```

Now I got report:

```
CONTRACT_NAME
   Deployment
      ✓ Should deployed test (247ms, 1455096 gas)
```

but I want got this

```
CONTRACT_NAME
   Deployment
      ✓ Should deployed test (123.5ms, 727548 gas)
```

terminal run(if it is important):

```
npx hardhat test --network localhost
```

versions:

```
"hardhat": "^2.11.2",
"hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
```

contract version:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
```

Ideas?
Need more details?

Thank you :)